# Powershell Transcript do not generate log file

Tags: powershell

First of all this is my first experience doing powershell script
but i have a problem with Start-Transcript to create a log file.  it don't work and i dont get any error..
This is my script.

```
Clear-Host
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_Script_log.txt" -Append -Force -NoClobber
$date = Get-Date
Write-Host "Oggi è il    $date"
Write-Host "Inizializzo il Programma di Controllo"
Write-Host "Verifico se il file di controllo esiste ed è accessibile"
$ChkFile = "C:\controllo.txt"
$FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile
If ($FileExists -eq $true)
{
    write-host "Il file esiste, quindi il disco virtuale è correttamente montato nel server."
    write-host "Termino la procedura e non faccio altro."
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Il file di controllo non è accessibile, procedo al montaggio tramite Mount-VHD"
    #Mount-VHD -Path \\TS-453A\ISCSI-Disks\ReplicaISCSI.vhdx #<Perfetto, Funzionante>#
    Write-Host "Montaggio disco virtuale completato, invio una mail all'amministratore per far verificare manualmente la cosa quanto prima"
    $login = "xxxxxxxx"
    $password = "xxxxxx" | Convertto-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force # Inserisco la password in chiaro, non è il massimo ma non so fare altrimenti
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Pscredential -Argumentlist $login, $password
    $From = "xxxx"
    $To = "xxxxxx"
    # $Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
    # $Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
    $Subject = "Email Subject"
    $Body = "Insert body text here"
    $SMTPServer = "xxxxxx"
    $SMTPPort = "25"
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
                     -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort `
                     -Credential $credentials -Priority High
    Write-Host "Email Inviata, termino la procedura."

}
Stop-Transcript
Pause
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Output seems to be ok
`>> Running (V1.ps1) Script...
>> Platform: V5 64Bit (STA)
Trascrizione avviata. File di output: C:\2017-06-21_Script_log.txt
Oggi è il    06/21/2017 00:04:11
Inizializzo il Programma di Controllo
Verifico se il file di controllo esiste ed è accessibile
Il file di controllo non è accessibile, procedo al montaggio tramite Mount-VHD
Montaggio disco virtuale completato, invio una mail all'amministratore per far verificare manualmente la cosa quanto prima
Email Inviata, termino la procedura.

>> Execution time: 00:00:02
>> Script Ended`

Comment: Write-Host outputs to the void.  If you want to capture your output with the Start-Transcript cmdlet, you need something that can be captured in the first place.  Depending on your English comprehension, I'd recommend reading through [this link on PowerShell streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` doesn't output to any stream and will not be captured.  Use `Write-Output` instead which spews to the Success/Output stream (aliases `Echo` and `Write`)

As a side-note, I would suggest not putting passwords as plaintext into scripts.  Instead, use something like:

```
(Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File .\pw.txt
```

This way the pw is minimally encrypted.  From there, you can use Get-Content and ConvertTo-SecureString

Lastly, in your `If` statement, you can just use `If ($FileExists)`.  It only has two states it can be, `$True` and `$False`; `-eq $true` is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried the script on another machine and log seem to work..
**********************
Inizio trascrizione Windows PowerShell
Ora di inizio: 20170621003210

**********************
Trascrizione avviata. File di output: C:\2017-06-21_Script_log.txt
Oggi è il    06/21/2017 00:32:10
Inizializzo il Programma di Controllo
Verifico se il file di controllo esiste ed è accessibile
Il file di controllo non è accessibile, procedo al montaggio tramite Mount-VHD
Montaggio disco virtuale completato, invio una mail all'amministratore 
Fine trascrizione Windows PowerShell
Ora di fine: 20170621003210

Comment: I really don't undersand why

Comment: @Posco I see you're trying to write to the C:\ directory.  It's possible you do not have permissions.